# Falha ao instalar .deb no Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, linux

Fiz o download de um arquivo .deb diretamente do site oficial (instalador do Astah Community) e, após concluído o download cliquei duas vezes sobre o arquivo.

A tela do Ubuntu Software foi aberta (como podemos observar na imagem ao final) e mandei instalar, clicando no botão **Instalar**.

Após isso, o processo de instalação simplesmente não se encerrou. Outro software que eu estava instalando (e que havia sido iniciado antes) funcionou perfeitamente, mas o Astah Community não.

O problema que isso me trouxe é que agora não consigo mais fazer um `upgrade` com o `apt`, já que sou informado que o pacote astah-community precisa ser reinstalado.

```
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
E: O pacote astah-community precisa ser reinstalado, mas não foi possível
encontrar um arquivo para o mesmo.
```

Refiz o download do .deb e tentei instalar novamente. Só que agora o processo nem se inicia mais.

Como reparo isso?
Pra mim tanto faz "finalizar" a instalação do Astah ou removê-lo de uma vez, para que o `apt` volte a funcionar.

OBS: estou utilizando o Ubuntu 16.04

[image: Ubuntu Software]

Comment: Tente instalar via terminal: sudo dpkg -i pacote.deb

Comment: Tenta rodar um `apt-get -f install`

Comment: O que o esse parâmetro `-f` faz?

Comment: @L.WD ele corrige pacotes quebrados.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelos comentários. Consegui resolver os problemas.

Comment: Apesar de ser sobre um software de UML e ter alguma ligação com o escopo, ainda sim fica mais para off-topic, pois o problema esta mais para ubuntu e não para o "software não funciona", por este motivo estou votando por fechar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segui as sugestões enviadas por comentários e consegui resolver.

Fiz a instalação utilizando `sudo dpkg -i pacote.deb` e o Astah funcionou perfeitamente. O interessante é que, ao fazer a instalação utilizando esse comando, visualizei um texto (possivelmente o "contrato" de uso do software) que antes (pelo Ubuntu Software) eu não visualizava.

Após a instalação, utilizei `sudo apt-get -f install` (comando que também me foi sugerido por comentário) e finalizei os reparos. Agora consigo utilizar o `apt upgrade`, que antes não conseguia.

Muito obrigado pelos comentários/ajuda.